# how to establish connection with remote desktop over internet using C++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, rdp

Given IP address, username, and password of a remote desktop, how to establish connection with it over internet using C++? Need a WinAPI function that can do that

Comment: What have you tried on this till now?

Comment: There is `WNetAddConnection2` but it makes connection to a network resource and can redirect a local device to the network resource. What I need is to get connected to a remote desktop through internet. There is _Remote Desktop Services API_, but I could not find which can do what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can use ShellExecute/CreateProcess with [MSTSC.EXE](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753907(v=ws.10).aspx). You find the documentation in the MSDN. Also can execute `MSTSC.EXE /?` to get a list of allowed options.

I.e.

```
MSTSC /v:"<computer>"
```

For password and username you need to create a RDP file, or you can use cmdkey, before you launch MSTSC.

```
cmdkey /generic:"<computer>" /user:"<username>" /pass:"<password>"
```

The disadvantage is that the password is stored on your local PC. You may execute

```
cmdkey /delete:"<computer>"
```

But anyhow for a short moment the username and password phrase is stored locally.